# Integrating 'cookies-next' with Axios Interceptors in Next.js

Tags: javascript

I've been attempting to integrate `getCookie()` and `setCookie()` functions from 'cookies-next' library within Axios interceptors in a Next.js application. Despite console logging the token and refreshToken values, setting the cookies using `setCookie()` seems to have no effect. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getCookie, setCookie } from "cookies-next";

const axiosUser = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_USER,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    withCredentials: true,
});

const axiosLogin = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_USER,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    withCredentials: true,
});

axiosUser.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const token = getCookie("TOKEN");
        console.log("««««« token »»»»»", token);
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);

axiosLogin.interceptors.response.use(
    async (response) => {
        const { token, refreshToken } = response.data;

        if (token) {
            setCookie("TOKEN", token);
            console.log("««««« token »»»»»", token);
        }
        if (refreshToken) {
            setCookie("REFRESHTOKEN", refreshToken);
            console.log("««««« refreshToken »»»»»", refreshToken);
        }
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);

export { axiosUser, axiosLogin };
```

Despite successfully retrieving the token and refreshToken values, setting cookies using `setCookie()` doesn't seem to have any effect. I've searched extensively but haven't found a solution. I'm seeking guidance on how to properly integrate 'cookies-next' functions within Axios interceptors in Next.js. Any advice or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: who can help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, getCookie and setCookie of "cookies-next" only work on client side in my context, if I use axios on client side, getCookie and setCookie will work, I know, there is a configuration for "cookies-next" it works on the server side, but in my context I can't do it on axios interceptor

this is what i want to do:

```
    import axios from "axios";
import { deleteCookie, getCookie, setCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

import { refreshAccessToken } from "./TokenService";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_USER,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = getCookie("TOKEN");

    if (token) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  async (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
  async (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalConfig = error.config;

    const refreshToken = getCookie("REFRESH_TOKEN");

    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && error?.response?.data === "Unauthorized" && refreshToken) {
      const newToken = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);

      console.log("««««« newToken »»»»»", newToken);

      if (newToken !== "Token refresh failed") {
        setCookie("TOKEN", newToken);

        originalConfig.sent = true;

        originalConfig.headers = {
          ...originalConfig.headers,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}`,
        };
      } else {
        deleteCookie("TOKEN");

        deleteCookie("REFRESH_TOKEN");

        signOut({ callbackUrl: "/log-in" });
      }

      return axiosClient(originalConfig);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export { axiosClient };
```